# Make view exposed filter shows results related to previous filter in view

Tags: views

About my form:
In my project, i'm having a form where project name field is select(drop down) and i have to enter a field(example "sub-project"). Then i will submit the form with project name from select(drop down) and i will type my sub-project name.

View Form:
Here, while showing the form results as table i want two exposed filters. they are
1. Project name(As select box in filter field)(**No problem in this part)
2.Sub-project name(As select box in filter field)(**Problem)

Question:
Now, if i select project name in filter(Example: Project Auro) then automatically i want the sub-project field(2nd exposed filter) to show the sub-projects as drop-down which are only related to Project Auro, that i submitted in form.

Please assist me, and Thanks in advance if you guide me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As always there are many ways to solve a problem in Drupal.

The easiest way here is probably the [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) module.

This way the "sub-project" form field will only appear after a user chooses the "project" filter.